# Solutions to $\sqrt[4]{1} + \sqrt[4]{16}$ in Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

The task states:

> In real numbers, $\sqrt[4]{1} + \sqrt[4]{16}$ = 3. In complex numbers we get more solutions.
>
> **a)** Determine how many solutions there are.
>
> **b)** Determine their absolute values.

According to the results, there are **16 distinct** solutions to the sum. However, it also says that the absolute values of the solutions are {$1; \sqrt{5}; 3$}.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Judging by the number of absolute values, I would say that there is a typo in the results and it should be **6** instead of **16**.

Nonetheless, I have no idea how to get to those values. If it's too easy, just give me hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope, there are $16$ solutions. There are four values for $\sqrt[4]{1}$ and four values for $\sqrt[4]{16}$.

Comment: In general the number of complex n$^{\text{th}}$ roots of a number is n.

Comment: All of the fourth roots of 1 are found through $z^4 - 1 = 0$ which, when factored via difference of squares, is very easy to solve.

Comment: @Guru: to be exact, except x=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16 is correct. Recall that the *absolute value* of a complex number is its magnitude - infinitely many share each nonzero magnitude. For example, $1$, $i $, $-1$, and $-i $ all have magnitude $1$.

$1$ has four fourth roots: $1, -1, i, -i $. $16$ also has four fourth roots; try to work them out. Each root of $1$ pairs with a root of $16$, for $4 \cdot 4$ total pairs.

Ignore the information about the magnitudes for now; just use it to check your work.

Comment: You should demonstrate that addition of any pair is different to the addition of the others.

Comment: That was much much easier than I thought. The problem was that, for some reason, I couldn't visualise it correctly despite knowing the theory behind it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For a visual answer, I've shown the four roots of $1$ added to each of the four roots of $16$ in the complex plane, making a nice grid of $16$ points, characterized by $|Re(z)|+|Im(z)|=(1\text{ or }3)$. As you can see, there are four solutions with $|z|=1$, four with $|z|=3$ and eight off the axes lying on the circle with $|z|=\sqrt 5$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Notice $\sqrt[4]{1}$ can take four values $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$. And the same with $\sqrt[4]{16}$, which can take $\{2,-2,2i,-2i\}$. So now you can form, how many sums choosing one element from each set?

Comment: "how many sums" => "how many different sums".